# How to trigger Firebase notifications using timestamp field?

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, notifications, timestamp

I am developing an app using Firebase as a backend with flutter. I am trying to add notifications functionality to the app. I know that firebase has push_notification service and most tutorials that I found are talking about how to set it for messaging apps. However, I am trying to notify the user based on the timestamp field in one of the documents in the database. I am not sure if there is a way to trigger the notifications locally (client side) or from the firebase.

Suppose the user has a document in the database for each assignment and each assignment has a due date as a filed in the database. I want to notify the user 24 hours before the assignment is due. Or possibly give the user the option to choose number of days/hours to be notified before each assignment is due.

Is there a way to set this functionality from firebase? How would you schedule the push-notification to be triggered?

Is there a way to set this functionality locally (client side)? How?

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in features to schedule notifications in Firebase based on a dynamic timestamp. Follow the following steps:

1. Setup Firebase Cloud Functions to send per device token-based
   Notifications. You need to upgrade to the Blaze plan to use these functionalities.

   [How to send Notifications using Firebase Functions](https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide/)
2. You can use `node-schedule` or `Cloud Scheduler` in **Firebase
   Functions**. Or alternatively, if a periodic timer solves your
   problem you can use `pub-sub scheduler`

   - [Pub-sub schedule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)
   - [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)
   - [Cloud scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler)